Why does the stopping potential correspond to zero current?
My textbook has derived an equation for the stopping potential during the photoelectric experiment as follows:
$$\frac{1}{2}mv_\text{max}^2=eV_0 \\ \implies V_0=\frac{mv^2_\text{max}}{2e}\implies V_0=\frac{h\nu-\phi}{e}.$$
Here, $\nu$ denotes the frequency of incident light, $\phi$ denotes the work function of the emitter electrode and $V_0$ denotes the stopping potential.
My question is: Why does $V_0=mv^2_\text{max}/2e$ correspond to zero photocurrent?
Not all electrons that travel in the discharge tube would have $v_\text{max}$ velocity right? Many of them would have a velocity $v$ less than $v_\text{max}$, and with this logic, since $eV_0>mv^2/2$, these electrons would begin to move in the opposite direction, and contribute to a slight current. For or any given potential difference, there would be some electrons who would be left with kinetic energy and would constitute a photocurrent, causing a non-zero ammeter reading.
The only condition under which I assume you could have a stopping potential corresponding to zero photocurrent is when the total rightward current is equal to the total leftward current. This could occur when:
$$V_0=\frac{mv^2_0}{2e}$$
where $v_0$ corresponds to the weighted mean of velocities of all electrons in the discharge tube. However, this doesn't seem to have been taken into account in the derivation in my textbook.
This was my logic so far; is there something I'm missing?

Your intuition would be right, if the circuit used in photoelectric experiments were closed. That is to say, in a closed circuit, it doesn't matter in which way the electrons flow, we will always register some current. Nonetheless, the photoelectric effect is typically studied with a circuit as the one below:

Source.
As you can see, this circuit is open, not closed. This is the key: if the photons are energetic enough, they will begin to separate electrons from the metalic surface. As you mention, not all of these electrons' velocity will be maximum, and therefore some of them will not make it to the other metal plate. Of course, these electrons will go back to the original plate (where else would they go?) but this will not contribute to the current, because the only time the circuit is closed is when the charges connect both metal plates. In order to register current in your circuit, you need for charges to actually go through it, and the only time this happens is when a charge goes from the first to the second plate. If it departs from the original plate but then goes back to it, then of course, you are not closing your circuit, and therefore the current you are registering is null.
As a bonus, you can think what happens when the potential ceases to be negative (stopping potential, as the one you are working with) and is instead positive (electrons that are freed are pulled towards the second plate). What current would you register then?

Wow, thanks a lot for this answer! Your explanation cleared up all my questions; about the question you gave, I assume you would register a photocurrent since the electrons would gain energy and reach the collecting electrode, completing the circuit.

Bingo! If you use a positive voltage, then the electrons would only need to be released (i.e: the minimum velocity needed for them to reach the other plate would be zero). Therefore, it doesn't matter how much you increase the voltage, the current you register would always be the same (all the released electrons would reach the plate). You can see the validation of your answer in the following graph: https://cdn1.byjus.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Photoelectric-Effect-6-700x343.png

This answer is correct, but only if you consider the average of many electron charges. Contrary to what you said, there is also a current in the outer circuit when you move an electron only for a short distance between the cathode and the anode.  A positive current when it moves towards the anode and a negative when it returns to the cathode. This is due to the time varying charges induced by the electron charge on the cathode and anode plates. Only the time average of the current produced by a single electrons  is zero, or the ensemble average current of many emitted and returning electrons.

@freecharly thanks for contributing! Would you mind editing my answer / posting your own discussing these details? Quite naturally, my answer can't be as complete as it gets as I'm still in second year, so my knowledge of circuits and quantum are not fully developed
